# CALL SUBSCREEN : <program> <dynpro> NO DYNPRO NAME​

Tags: abap, dynpro

I have a minimal example below (executable program + 2 dynpro screens), and I get the error while running it (nothing displayed); pressing Enter then leaves the program completely:

> CALL SUBSCREEN : ZZSRO_TEST14A 0003 NO DYNPRO NAME​
>
> [image: CALL SUBSCREEN : NO DYNPRO NAME​]

Program `ZZSRO_TEST14A`:

- Title: "Display Flight Data"
- Code:

  ```
  REPORT zzsro_test14a.
  CALL SCREEN 3.
  ```

Dynpro `3`:

- Type: general screen
- Layout: only a sub-screen element `MYSUBSCREEN`
- Flow logic:

  ```
  PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.
    CALL SUBSCREEN mysubscreen INCLUDING sy–repid '0004'.
  PROCESS AFTER INPUT.
    CALL SUBSCREEN mysubscreen.
  ```

Dynpro `4`:

- Type: sub-screen
- Layout: only one text element to display `test`
- Flow logic:

  ```
  PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.
  PROCESS AFTER INPUT.
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This message

```
CALL SUBSCREEN : <program> <dynpro> NO DYNPRO NAME​
```

means that in the flow logic of dynpro `<program> <dynpro>` (so `ZZSRO_TEST14A` `0003` in your case), there is a CALL SUBSCREEN statement, i.e. this one

```
CALL SUBSCREEN mysubscreen INCLUDING sy–repid '0004'.
```

and the program name indicated after INCLUDING (dynpro being always referred by program name and dynpro number) is empty. NB: the program and dynpro can be indicated either statically via quotes, as done for `'0004'`, or as constant/variable, without quotes, as done for `sy–repid`.

`sy-repid` is a valid system constant containing the program name (i.e. `ZZSRO_TEST14A` in your case)

Surprisingly, all seems good in your code.

In fact, the error is a **simple typo error** because of the hyphen/dash character in `sy–repid` which is the EN DASH U+2013 character. It makes it an invalid constant/variable whose replacement value is an empty string.

Solution: use a normal hyphen/minus character U+002D i.e. `sy-repid` all will run fine:

[image]

NB: in case of other situations with invalid program/dynpro, instead of message "NO DYNPRO NAME", there will be these runtime errors (short dumps in transaction code `ST22`).

- If the program name doesn't exist, there will be the runtime error `LOAD_PROGRAM_NOT_FOUND`.
- If the program name exists but the dynpro number doesn't exist in that program, there will be the runtime error `DYNPRO_NOT_FOUND`.
- If the dynpro exists but is not of type sub-screen, there will be the runtime error `DYNP_WRONG_SCREEN_TYPE`.